# How to make a JNI application support multiple versions of JVM on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a JNI application that was compiled on a Linux machine with Java 6. When I try to run it on a machine which has Java 7 installed I get the following error:

> ./test: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

The problem is that libjvm.so is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server` on the second machine and this directory is not in `RPATH`:

```
$ objdump -x test | grep RPATH
  RPATH                /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/ja
  va-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

An obvious solution is to add `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server` to `RPATH`, but I wonder if there is a more general way to address this problem and to make an application work with whatever JVM is installed on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that works well on all Debian-based distributions including Debian itself, Ubuntu, Mint, etc: use `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/...` instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/...` in `RPATH`. Similarly for `Centos/RHEL` support `/usr/lib/jvm/java/...` can be added as well.

And as a fallback solution, `JAVA_HOME` or looking up the location of `java` executable can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the library path:

```
java -Djava.library.path="path_here"
```

Edit: note that it expects a folder to look in, not a specific file. :)

Edit2: the path can be relative.

Comment: The question is about finding the JVM, not about finding a JNI library.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could use a registry key. But your question is about Linux and your options there are limited. You could always use dirty hacks like finding the `java` executable on `$PATH`, but the cleanest way is `$JAVA_HOME`. It's not foolproof like the Windows registry key, because the user still has to create it manually. But `$JAVA_HOME` has basically become the standard solution for finding the JVM. Many other software products are relying on it, so chances are, your users might have it already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the problem with `$JAVA_HOME` is that it is not set by default on many systems.